# jQuery data Table : rewriting each row's title with row index after sorting

Tags: jquery, datatables

Thanks to Andrew James, I was able to write the row's index to the row's title property.
Now I have this code that does it after each sorting but I was looking for a way to beautify the code

If no one can, then this may serve as a solution for others, because it works

Cheers

```
    var table = $(".table").DataTable(...);
    //jquery code to rewrite the row index number to each row title after sorting
    function writeRowIndex() {
        var rowIdx = 1;
        table.rows().every(function (rowIdx) {
            $(this.node()).attr('title', rowIdx);
            rowIdx++;
        });
    }
    //call the function on loading the page;
    writeRowIndex();
    //calling function after each sorting event
    var headers = table.columns().header().toArray();
    $(headers).on('click', function () {
        writeRowIndex();//call existing function
    });
```